# One F# 4.1 compiler includes targetPlatform value of netstandard, the other does not

Tags: f#

The F# 4.1 compiler on my build machine has slightly different `--targetProfile` options than the F# 4.1 compiler on my dev machine.

On my dev machine, when I type `fsc.exe -?` the output includes the following:

```
Microsoft (R) F# Compiler version 4.1
     :
--targetprofile:<string>
Specify target framework profile of this assembly.
Valid values are mscorlib, netcore or netstandard.
     :
```

On my build server, the same command outputs the following:

```
Microsoft (R) F# Compiler version 4.1
     :
--targetprofile:<string>
Specify target framework profile of this assembly.
Valid values are mscorlib or netcore.
     :
```

Notice that the dev machine includes `netstandard` as a valid value, but the build server does not.

Consequently, when I try to build my project on the build server, I get a compile time error of "`error FS1052: Invalid value 'netstandard' for '--targetprofile'`"

What is going on? Is there a way to display the *real* version number of an F# 4.1 compiler? `fsc.exe --version` does not work.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is to do with the F# compiler version but rather the .NET SDK(s) installed.
Check [the target framework TFMs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/frameworks).

I have `mscorlib, netcore or netstandard` and I will take a stab at where they come from:

- `mscorlib` from full framework...comes with Windows
- `netcore` installed with VS 2017 when selecting ".NET desktop development"
- `netstandard` installed with NET Core SDK

If this is the case I would imagine installing [.NET Core SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core) on the build server would sort it out since you seem to be targeting netstandard.

Comment: The TFS admin sent me a screenshot showing that the .NET Core 2.0 SDK is installed. Still, the F# compiler says, "Valid values are mscorlib or netcore". Very frustrating.

Comment: Is there a `global.json` in the project?

Comment: The project is an F# class library project. There is no global.json. However, the fsc.exe -? is run independently of a project.

Comment: Are you building it on your local machine with fsc? Or with VS? Which VS version? If building for netstandard I use `dotnet build` in which case it will use the sdk on the path found with `dotnet --version` unless there is a `global.json` up the tree somewhere specifying a specific sdk version.

Comment: When I build my projects on dev and build server, I use `dotnet build`. However, the fsc.exe -? is run independently of a project.